# django: use a string to select a specifc model

Tags: django

What I want to do be able to use the name of a model as an input to a function so the objects methods can be performed against the specified model. For example:

```
from app.models import model1, model2

def select_all_from_model(model_name):
    all = model_name.objects.all()
    return all

all = select_all_from_model('model1')
```

`all = model_name.objects.all()` is a nonsense line. I need to have a model object, not a string name, for the `objects.all()` select to work. How do I load the model object based on the string value of `model_name`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use models.get_model() function:

```
>>> model_class = models.get_model('App', 'Model1')
>>> model_class.objects.all()
>>> [...]
```

That's if you need to use a string. But you can pass classes around in python. Here's an example:

```
>>> from app.models import Model1
>>> select_all_from_model(Model1)
>>> [...]
```

Comment: Thanks. `models.get_model` solves my issues. Makes it so much easier to aggregate data spread across multiple datatables.

Comment: You're welcome. Glad it helps. It also solves circular imports ;)