# Calling filter with variable name for Model Name (Django)

Tags: python, django, filter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [django: use a string to select a specifc model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14651438/django-use-a-string-to-select-a-specifc-model)

Example: (Django, views.py)

```
def create(request, mod):  
    #mod is a modelname    
    if request.method == 'POST':  
        form = globals()[mod+"Form"](request.POST)  
        if form.is_valid():  
            new_file_num = form.save(commit=False)  
            >>>> if entry.objects.filter(fileTypeNumber=1).exists():
```

**My problem is here.**

```
if entry.objects.filter( ....
```

---

Instead, I want to:

```
mod = entry;  
if mod.objects.filter( ....
```

---

The overall goal here is to use the same "view" for multiple models with different fields.
Is there a better way to do this?  The view is essentially assigning a filenumber and then saving it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Pull the class from the instance.

```
mod = my_instance.__class__
if mod.objects.filter(fileTypeNumber=1).exists():
```

Answer (score 0):

You could maybe do something like:

```
from models import Foo, Bar

def create_view(model):
    # model is the actual model class (not instance)
    def view(request):
        form = globals()[model.__name__ + "Form"]
        if model.objects.filter(fileTypeNumber=1).exists():
            pass
            # whatever you do with it
    return view

foo_view = create_view(Foo)
bar_view = create_view(Bar)
```

This would make two views for the `Foo` and `Bar` models. But if you've got different fields for each model (or if you're validating or doing anything else that needs handling differently), you may be better off just making different views by hand for each one instead of doing this kind of abstract creation function.